# Torque map: dates by year; year in slider text

Tags: carto, cartocss, torque

I would like to put the year in the slider text and for the data to be scrolled through via year.

[image: data looks like this]

Apparently it was working until three weeks ago, and now doesn't. In particular the slider now shows wonky month/day combos rather than just the year. Just the year is what is desired.

How might I fix this?

Initially I fixed the *really* wonky dates by fixing the -torque-frame-count in the css from default 256 to 227 (for years 1787-2014), which is the number of years. But now, instead of getting random dates, it tends to flip between Jan 1 and Dec 31 on both sides of the date range. It seems disproportionately difficult to find information to get this done - surely this is a common request?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have just tried to improve on this solution by doing a new select, but the value returned is a number not a date. This causes the slider to start at 0 rather than at 1747.  SELECT cartodb_id,the_geom,context_for_making_constitution, first, key_provisions, lat, lon, location_vis, region, state, the_geom_webmercator, EXTRACT(YEAR from year2) as date_part, years_constitutions_made FROM with_latlons_years

Comment: When I read the postgreSQL docs on date, I tried changing the EXTRACT - which returns a double - to date_trunc which returns a datestamp, but that's returning 1893-01-01T00:00:00Z rather than 1893.

Answer (score 1):

We did some changes on the intervals of Torque.

Yesterday we did a fix for this: if the data range is bigger than one year, then it'll show as always. I think this fix will solve your issue, as I'm seeing that you're using different years as the date.